# visibility (overlapping) problems with CABasicAnimation CALayer transformations

Tags: objective-c, uiview, calayer, transformation, cabasicanimation

I have two UIImageViews on my object, and I'm trying to animate them to page like a book. I used some of the built in animations for a while (`UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromLeft/Right`), and decided I could do better. I found a nice example for half of the animation I wanted here: http://fiftysixtysoftware.com/blog/2009/uiview-pageopen-sample-project/

I was able to extrapolate from there to get my animation working... but the problem I'm having is that my animating image (the right image) always shows up *beneath* the left image.

Here's code in the init:

```
// set up some rects for use later
landscapeLeftRect = CGRectMake(0, 12, 512, 725);
landscapeRightRect = CGRectMake(512, 12, 512, 725);

// all our images
imageLeft = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:portraitRect];
imageRight = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:landscapeRightRect];
```

...and performing the actual animation (note that this is the second half of the animation, the half that "overlaps" with my imageLeft view):

```
// set the image to be nextLeft
//[imageRight setImage:image.nextLeft];
[self.view sendSubviewToBack:imageLeft];
[self.view bringSubviewToFront:imageRight];
//[imageRight.layer setZPosition:1.0f];
[imageRight setFrame:landscapeLeftRect];

// remove any previous animations
[imageRight.layer removeAllAnimations];

// set up the anchorPoint and center
if (imageRight.layer.anchorPoint.x != 1.0f) {
    imageRight.layer.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(1.0f, 0.5f);
    imageRight.center = CGPointMake(imageRight.center.x + imageRight.bounds.size.width/2.0f, imageRight.center.y);
}

// create an animation to hold the first half of the page turning forward
CABasicAnimation *transformAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform"];
transformAnimation.removedOnCompletion = YES;
transformAnimation.duration = 0.40f;
transformAnimation.delegate = self;
transformAnimation.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut];
// start the animation from the current state
CATransform3D endTransform = CATransform3DMakeRotation(3.141f/2.0f,
                                                       0.0f,
                                                       -1.0f,
                                                       0.0f);
// these values control the 3D projection outlook
endTransform.m34 = -0.001f;
endTransform.m14 = 0.0015f;
transformAnimation.fromValue = [NSValue valueWithCATransform3D:endTransform];
// we should end up at the beginning...
transformAnimation.toValue = [NSValue valueWithCATransform3D:CATransform3DIdentity];

[imageRight.layer addAnimation:transformAnimation forKey:nil];
```

Things I've tried: (you can see both in the code above)

- bringSubviewToFront/sendSubviewToBack
- setting a Z index on the layer

Thanks in advance for any advice or wisdom. Again, the problem is with my imageLeft always displaying on top of the animation.

Comment: Anyone looking at this question now (over two years later) should look into the page view controller (`UIPageViewController`) and it's animations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I faced the same problem and just found that you can fix it by setting the zPosition of the view.
I used something like this:

> viewThatShouldBeSentToTheBack.layer.zPosition=-10000;

Answer (score 0):

I found that once I brought the animated view to the front, everything worked. I am working on a page turn animation and was having trouble when paging backwards showing the page overlay in a counterclockwise fashion. My trouble was that I just couldn't see the animation since it was behind the page it was supposed to overlay.

Comment: The crux of my problem is that bringSubviewToFront does NOTHING for me.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that you are iterating through the array correctly when adding the page view to the superview? Naturally, you would want to put the last page down first so that your first page is on top... I'm not insulting your intelligence - layers can be tricky.

Comment: I'm wasn't iterating through the subviews at any point. There is an interesting dichotomy here in that the animation I used can only be applied to layers, but I was otherwise only working with views that have already been added to the parent.

Answer (score 0):

I came across this precise problem and I found the only way to avoid it is by setting the zPosition of tyhe background to a big negative number. It would be nice to know exactly why…